# Expand a div's height if it's shorter than viewport

Tags: css, html

I have a div with three tabs, and a footer, the problem is that if one of the tab's content is smaller than the viewport a blank space appears under the footer.
[This is one of the tabs working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD6Bm.png)

[And this is what happens when I switch the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nqTA.png)

I need that div to stretch to the bottom, but I can't find a way to do it

The following is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="padding-top: 3.5rem;">
        <navbar>
            Navbar
        </navbar>
        <div class="container" style="width:100%;display:block;overflow:auto;">
            Tabs and everything else
        </div>
        <footer class="py-5 bg-dark" style="position: relative;bottom: 0;width: 100%;">
            Footer
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

By the way, I'm using Bootstrap 4

Comment: So you want the footer to be always below the browser, but not fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your header and footer a specific height, say `40px`, then you can give your div a `min-height: calc(100%-80px)`. This will make it occupy the full height of its parent minus the height of the header and footer. I added the background colors just for demo:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="padding-top: 3.5rem;">
        <navbar style="background-color: yellow; display: block; height: 40px;">
            Navbar
        </navbar>
        <div class="container" style="width: 100%; min-height: calc(100% - 80px); display: block; overflow: auto; background-color: cyan;">
            Tabs and everything else
        </div>
        <footer class="py-5 bg-dark" style="position: relative; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: yellow;">
            Footer
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```